# Correcto uso de variables static dentro de una clase

Tags: java

Tengo una duda respecto al uso de la palabra reservada static cuando se declara dentro de una clase objeto. No he logrado encontrar una respuesta que me aclare, espero que podáis ayudarme. Os cuento un ejemplo del escenario que me ha sucedido:

Tengo una clase que define un objeto, por ejemplo, Persona. Mi programa recoge información de personas de un fichero y por cada lectura del fichero me crea un objeto Persona. Desde otra clase, recojo toda la colección de objetos personas que he creado y por cada una, en función de si es un hombre o una mujer, por ejemplo, hago una acción.

Dentro del objeto, tenía declaradas las variables como static, por ejemplo:

```
private static String sexo;
private static int edad;
...
```

Mientras estoy depurando, cuando estoy recogiendo la información de cada objeto, en la colección tal que así:

```
for (Object element : collection_){
        if (element instanceof Units){
            Units unit_ = (Units)element;
...
```

, me doy cuenta de que en los objetos de la colección no veo estas variables declaradas como static, pero aquellas que están declaradas sin la palabra static sí puedo verlas (me refiero a cuando pongo el ratón encima de la palabra collection_ y veo el desplegable con todas las unidades registradas). En cuanto he quitado la palabra static de ellas ya he podido verlas durante la depuración.

Mi pregunta es, ¿por qué no puedo ver las declaradas como static si son propiedades de mi objeto? es decir, las tengo puestas como variables globales, con la palabra static puesta. No entiendo por qué con static puesto no las puedo ver y sin static sí que puedo.

Disculpad si está repetida la pregunta, vengo de .NET y hay cosas de Java que todavía no tengo del todo claras, y esto no consigo aclarármelo en ningún hilo ni con la doc de java para este caso concreto. Espero que con el ejemplo pueda valer, solo necesito entender bien el concepto pero meter aquí el código que estoy usando va a ser peor porque uso librerías externas que pueden liar la pregunta.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo primero que hay que entender, es que las variables declaradas como `static`pertenecen a la **Clase** y no al objeto particular. Es decir, cuando creas varios objetos, no habrá una copia para cada objeto de esas variables, ya que pertenece como he dicho a la Clase.

Comment: muchas gracias @DiegoLoL !! Esto me encaja ahora con lo que me estaba pasando. Veía que recorriendo la colección, para todos los objetos me traía siempre la misma propiedad, que era la del último objeto que había registrado en la colección, y por lo que dices, como pertenece a la clase y no al objeto, solo voy a poder recuperar el valor del último que he metido ¿estoy en lo cierto? Muchas gracias de nuevo!!

Comment: Exacto, todos los objetos comparten la misma variable.

Comment: Esto en c# funcionaba exactamente igual :/

Answer (score 1):

Primero debemos tomar en consideracion que Static es utilizado en varios aspectos de Java no solo en variable sino ademas en Bloques de codigo, en metodos, en clases, en imports, y se relacionan pero realizan algunas cosas un tanto diferentes. dado a que la pregunta es especificamente con Variables me referire en especifico a ello. pero para mas informacion sobre static ver: [Static Class, Block, Methods](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-static-class-block-methods-variables/) y 
[Static Import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

sintaxis:

```
<modificador de acceso> static tipo_dato nombre_variable;
```

la variable `static` es una variable que se define a nivel de **clase** (osea *no pertenece a Ninguna instancia*, sino a la Clase como tal) y se puede decir que es una variable que es compartida por todas las instancias de una clase (pueden accesar a esta variable) estas variable son creadas cuando se carga la clase en memoria (ya sea cuando se cargan dinamicamente o cuando se inicia el JVM)

cuando utilizar variables `static`? existen varios esenarios por ejemplo supongamos que en tu ejemplo se desea saber la cantidad de `Persona` que se crean. en este caso creamos una variable `static` contador:

```
static int contador=0
```

(hay aspectos de threading que pueden ser necesarios pero eso no es el foco de la pregunta por tanto ignoremos eso por ahora)

ahora por ejemplo para realizar el conteo se tiene que:

```
/*constructor de Persona*/
public Persona(...){
//...
//otras inicializaciones
//...
contador++;
}
```

de esta forma tenemos una variable que le pertenese a Persona que lleva el conteo total de personas Creadas y de ser necesario podemos tener un metodo (`static`) que nos indique cuantas `Persona` se ahn creado:

```
public static int getPersonaCount(){
    return contador;
}
```

o si la variable es accesible por otras clases se puede acceder(public acces):

```
Persona.contador; 
// o dado getPersonaCount
Persona.getPersonaCount();
```

NOTA: tambien es posible acceder las variables estaticas mediante el Objeto, pero esto no es recomendado por ejemplo:

```
Persona Maria= ...  
//...
Maria.contador; //-> se puede, pero no es recomendado, inclusive los IDE te lo indican:
```

[image: IDE ejemplo]

por otro lado como OP menciona:

> ```
> private static String sexo;
> private static int edad;
> ```

estas variables en particular aparentan ser de la Persona en particular (instancia) por tanto no son variables que sea recomendable que sean `static` dado a que cada persona tiene sexo diferente y edad diferente **no son attributos compartidos!** lo que si es compartido es lo *binario* del sexo en cuyo caso se puede utlizar variables `static` para las opciones (aunque es recomendable utilizar [Enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) para esto pero para demostracion del ejemplo utilizemos static)

```
public class Persona{
    //variable de sexo
    private Sexo sexoPersona;
//...
//definicion de la clase persona metodos, variables etc...
//...
//final para que nadie pueda modificar esta clase.
    public final static class Sexo {
       public static final Sexo MASCULINO  = new Sexo("masulino");
       public static final Sexo FEMENINO  = new Sexo("Femenino");
       private final String valor;

        private Sexo(String val) {
            valor = val;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return valor;
        }

    }
}
```

en este caso podemos ver que creamos una clase `static` la cual define 2 ***constantes*** `estaticas` `static final` genera una variable que solo puede ser instanciada una unica ves. (esta forma de crear variables es tambien utilizado por el patron ***Singleton***, donde la instancia unica es `static final` y instanciada una unica ves.) este ejemplo son 2 Instancias y por tanto no es Singleton...

como le damos un valor del sexo de la persona? mediante el uso de `Persona.Sexo` ejemplo:

```
//los siguientes variables son public(tanto la clase como la instancia)
//por tanto se puede utilizar dentro y fuera de la clase Persona,
//pero le pertenese a Persona:
Persona.Sexo.MASCULINO;
// o
Persona.Sexo.FEMENINO;
```

finalmente

> ¿por qué no puedo ver las declaradas como static si son propiedades de mi objeto?

esto se debe a que estas usando las Variables `static` mal. la forma en que esta formulada esta pregunta lo determina: *`static si son propiedades de mi objeto`*, ***NO!*** por el contrario, si son `static` NO son Variables del Objeto, sino de la Clase y por tanto compartida Por todas las instancias de la Clase aka (Todos los objetos Persona)

> cuando pongo el ratón encima de la palabra collection_ y veo el desplegable con todas las unidades registradas

esto es dependiente del IDE mas que del uso de `static` pero eh de asumir que la razon es por que el IDE prioriza mostrar las variables del Objeto que las de la clase por ejemplo en Netbeans se pueden ver las variables en un apartado para static:

[image: static variables]

Comment: Buenísima respuesta @Silencio2. Mil gracias por esta aclaración!